# Running Construct 2 for Mac

Tags: html, construct-2

I would like to run construct 2 on Mac. It seems that construct 2 can only run on windows. Is there any solution for Mac? Need some guidance on this....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tom here from Scirra!

We don't officially support Mac I'm afraid at the moment, although some users are reporting sucess using Construct 2 on a Mac through a virtual machine (VM) like Parallels.

If you have a VM, try [downloading the free edition](http://www.scirra.com/construct2/releases/r95) of Construct 2 and running it to see if it works for you.

Comment: create a version for mac... U are losing out on a lot of users because of not having a version for mac... it's just my opinion... having a version for mac will definitely help a lot of them...

Comment: @Lakesh thanks for the suggestion, we're aware of the demand.

Comment: ok.. just a suggestion....u already doing a great job...

Answer (score 1):

wanted to use construct 2, but had to use gamesalad just because it's more stable or AVAILABLE to osx!.